# incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from int to byte error?

Tags: java

Why b=b+8 throws an error where b+=8 dosent.

```
public static void main(String []args){
    byte b = 6;
    b=b+8;
    //b+=8;
    System.out.println(b);
    b+=7;
    System.out.println(b);
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because `b=b+8` is not exactly equivalent to `b+=8`.

According to the language specification, section 15.26.2:

> A compound assignment expression of the form `E1 op= E2` is equivalent to `E1 = (T) ((E1) op (E2))`, where `T` is the type of `E1`, except that `E1` is evaluated only once.

It also gives you an example:

> For example, the following code is correct:
>
> ```
> short x = 3;
> x += 4.6;
> ```
>
> and results in x having the value 7 because it is equivalent to:
>
> ```
> short x = 3;
> x = (short)(x + 4.6);
> ```

So `+=` not only assigns the sum to the variable, but it also casts the sum to the type of the left hand side variable. `b=b+8` does not do this.

Why does `b=b+8` produce the warning then?

This is because the `+` operator, when used on `byte` types, also performs numeric promotion. The type of the expression `b+8` is actually `int`. Therefore the compiler tells you that you are converting an `int` to a `byte`.